# Разбить строку в массив JS

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

`const str = 'test1 test2="option1 option2" blabla="option1"'`

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно разбить строку, что бы в итоге получился массив

`const arr = ['test1', 'test2="option1 option2"', 'blabla="option1"']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться регулярным выражением, `/[^\s"']+("([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')?/`

Выбираем все последовательности кроме пробелов и кавычек, после которых могут идти последовательности в кавычках

```js
const str = 'test1 test2="option1 option2" blabla="option1"'

const result = 'test1 test2="option1 option2" blabla="option1"'.match(/[^\s"']+("([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')?/g);

console.log(result);
```

<sub>на основе ответа [@Jan Goyvaerts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/366532/2881286)</sub>